# Extenstion functor on quotient map

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\rho$ be the half sum of positive roots in $\Phi^+$, $M_x$ be the Verma module with highest weight $x\cdot(-2\rho)$ and $L_w$ be the simple highest weight module with highest weight $w\cdot(-2\rho)$.

I want to show $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}}(M_x,L_w)\neq 0\implies\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}}(M_x,M_w)\neq 0$.

**My attempt:**

Let $T(B):=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}}(M_x,B)$. Denote by $R^iT$ the $i$-th right derived functor of $T$. Then $R^iT(B)=\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}}^i(M_x,B)$.
Let $\pi_w:M_w\to L_w$ be the quotient map.

Apply functor $R^iT$ to this, we get $R^iT(\pi_w):\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}}^i(M_x,M_w)\to \mathrm{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}}^i(M_x,L_w)$.

If I can show $R^iT(\pi_w)$ is a nonzero map, then I am done.

**My question:**

1. How to show $R^iT(\pi_w)$ is a nonzero map?
2. How to show $\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}}(M_x,L_w)\neq 0\implies\mathrm{Ext}^i_{\mathcal{O}}(M_x,M_w)\neq 0$ in case (1) is false?